# jQuery: Getting the "raw" content of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this div:

```
<div id="test">
    {{? a && b || c < 0}}
        <div>Pece &alt; Love!</div>
    {{?}}
</div>
```

I neet do get its content just like it's reported above (che curly braces syntax is for a template engine).

Unfortunately, neither .html() nor .text() work:

```
// $('#test').text() 
{{? a && b || c < 0}}
    Pece &alt; Love!
{{?}}
```

.text() gets rid of tags

```
// $('#test').html()
{{? a &amp;&amp; b || c &lt; 0 }}
    <div>Pece &amp;alt; Love!</div>
{{?}}
```

.html() encodes the ampersands (and < >).

Any help? Thanks

Comment: You have to do this before or after the template is replaced?

Comment: What's wrong with the output of `.text()`?

Comment: That HTML no longer exists as far as the browser is concerned. Once it's parsed (and it will be parsed as HTML, you can't stop that) it only exists as HTML.

Comment: Your problem is that your original HTML isn't valid. It will work, but you aren't meant to have `&`s and `<`s just derping around like that.  I also don't think &alt; is a real entity.

Answer (score 8):

It's not a good idea to store your templates as HTML. Store them inside of `<script>` tags with a custom mimetype:

```
<script type="text/your-template" id="template">
    {{? a<b && b>c }}
        <div>Peace &amp; Love!</div>
    {{?}}
</script>
```

Storing templates that aren't HTML as HTML will yield undesirable results, as you've noticed:

- Your original markup is gone. What you see when you look at the `.innerHTML` property is what the browser interpreted your template to be if it was valid HTML, which can change it: http://jsfiddle.net/ZFd6a/3/
- `a<b && b>c` will turn into `ac`, as the middle portion will be interpreted as an element.
- Stray lesser-than and greater-than signs will be turned into character entities.
- You have to use HTML character entities.

You're entirely at the mercy of the browser's HTML parser. When you move your template into `<script>` tags with a mimetype that isn't reserved for JavaScript, your template is treated as a string, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks, i'm aware of this, and when i use doTjs i generally do so. In this case, though, I must use regular tags.

Comment: I should explain how the whole application works, and it's not small. Here html is not used for its normal purpose, but it's a definition language (semantic xml for those who know html).

Comment: @pistacchio: Once you pass off your HTML to the browser, your original markup is gone. The browser parses it and changes the structure: http://jsfiddle.net/ZFd6a/3/